# Performance drop on INSERT INTO SELECT FROM

Tags: mysql, tokudb

We have a "system" with a website.

When data is added (never updated old data), we create large "temp_data" table fill it with the new data - couple of million rows, then insert into the "main_data" table:

```
insert into main_data select * from temp_data;
```

main_data is toku_db engine, temp_data is myisam engine.

Often during the update, the website stop responding until data is fully inserted:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

and / or

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away
```

Any way I can do the insert "slower". Insert is always new data, it never updates anything.

Comment: Work in smaller batches?

Comment: You may try `INSERT LOW_PRIORITY ..`. In this case the insertion have the priority less than those for SELECT queries.

Comment: did not know you can use low priority there

Comment: Why insert into one temporary table, only to re-insert the same data into your main table?...seems like double the work.

Comment: `LOW_PRIORITY` _may_ be limited to MyISAM, not Tokudb??

Comment: @Nick - check the processlist; perhaps there are a lot of threads competing for access.  And _that_ may be the source of the problem.